# jquery function on click event in odoo is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i am trying bellow jquery code to perform some dynamic changes to my front view to make the odoo switch toggle to behave like radio button.so it could be selected one at a time like radio button

Note: console.log("test") is working but the code with css selector is not working

please guide me how i run my script to work it fine

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".wk_checked_question").click(function(){
            alert("you click me!");
          
        });
        console.log("test");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
*test.html**

     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="question_id" style="width:70%">Q1.  t-shirt coler 
            size</td>
            <td class="question_id" style="width:50%">$ 120.00</td>
            <td><label class="switch">
            input class="wk_checked_question" data-id="2" type="checkbox">
            <span class="check_box round"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="question_id" style="width:70%">Q2.  t-shirt size</td>
        <td class="question_id" style="width:50%"> Free</td>
        <td>
          <label class="switch">
           <input class="wk_checked_question" data-id="1" type="checkbox">
           <span class="check_box round"></span>
          </label>
        </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML as well.

Comment: What does `console.log($(".wk_checked_question"))` give you when placed as the first line of doc.ready?   "dynamic changes" implies the `.wk_checked_question` is loaded *after* the doc.ready - so you'll need event delegation  `$(document).on("click", ".wk_checked_question", function() ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: let me review it.@freedomn-m

Comment: its not worked in my case

Comment: In Odoo you use the `odoo widget pattern` to load your code. you also need to register your javascipt. so to help you we need a clear description of what you need to do. in addition to your entire module code & how you structure your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click",".wk_checked_question",function(ev){
      $(".wk_checked_question").each((i,cb)=>cb.checked=(cb==this));
      this.checked=true; // a "real" radio button cannot be unchecked ...
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:500px">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="question_id" style="width:70%">Q1.  t-shirt color size</td>
      <td class="question_id" style="width:50%">$ 120.00</td>
      <td><label class="switch"><input class="wk_checked_question" data-id="2" type="checkbox">
         <span class="check_box round"></span></label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="question_id" style="width:70%">Q2.  t-shirt size</td>
     <td class="question_id" style="width:50%"> Free</td>
     <td>
       <label class="switch">
        <input class="wk_checked_question" data-id="1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="check_box round"></span></label></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

After a click on a checkbox the `.each()` loop goes over all checkboxes with the same class and sets only the one being identical to the clicked ono (`this`). All others are unchecked.

I used "delegated event attachment" with `jQuery.on()` as suggested in @freedomn-m's comment. This has the advantage that it will work on target elements (`.wk_checked_question`) that don't even exist at the time of the event attachment.

Your HTML was also missing the `<table>` tags around your `<tbody>` which I added.

**Edit**

Coming back to this answer I realized that I could simplify the script even further and allow for an option to be unselected again by using this:

```
$("body").on("click",".wk_checked_question",function(ev){
 let newstate=this.checked;
 $(".wk_checked_question").prop("checked",false);
 this.checked=newstate
});
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir its really work for me @car10m